# How to clean up a timed out request to prevent a memory leak?

Tags: python, docker, memory-leaks, fastapi

Structure: A FastAPI service wrapped in a docker container with a 1gb memory limit.

User: A script that sends requests to this docker container.

Problem: Whenever a request is sent to the service that reaches the timeout limit, a memory leak occurs, because the request is not actually cancelled. Rather, as far as I can see, the request is parked, the blocking call in my script (`requests.post`) throws an error, which I can catch in a try/except and continue with the next request. However, the memory from the failed request is not released in the docker container.

FastAPI endpoint:

```
@app.post("/extract", response_model=ExtractionResponse)
def extract(request: ExtractionRequest) -> ExtractionResponse:
    result = app.state.model.inference(request.sample)
    return ExtractionResponse(sample=result)
```

"User" script:

```
for sample in tqdm(data):
    try:
        requests.post(
            url=f"http://{args.ip}:{args.port}/api/v1/extract", 
            data=json.dumps(sample), 
            timeout=5.0
        )
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        print(sample_data)
```

Executed with `CMD ["uvicorn", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080", "main:app"]` within the docker container.

So let's assume for some sample that `app.state.model.inference` or any other part of the request handling hangs indefinitely, this means the request will be kept in memory, causing a leak, even if the user is no longer waiting for a response from this request.

My question, therefore, is: How can I cancel the request if the blocking call waiting for it has moved on to other things?

Comment: That would depend on how you're running your FastAPI application - the connection handler needs to know that the caller has disappeared and cancel the internally running code. How you do that depends on what application you're using to run the FastAPI application (uvicorn, gunicorn, uwsgi, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I've added the call to uvicorn that is performed in the Dockerfile.